# Limit number of posts in WP Carrington JAM framework

Tags: wordpress, carrington

While using the Wordpress Carrington JAM framework, the number of posts being shown in my **Search Results, Archives**, and **Category** pages does not follow the value I typed in Settings > Reading.

In my Settings, I typed the number 2 in the field *"Blog pages show at most"* but whenever I view those 3 pages it shows all results instead of only 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the setting is not included in the theme options page for Carrington JAM. But I found it anyway in the file *themes/carrington-core/ajax-load.php* in the function `cfct_posts_per_archive_page_setting()`.

Default was 25 which is why so many results were being displayed. I changed it to something lower.